# Presto SQL - Trouble with converting date in varchar to date format

Tags: sql, date, presto

I am having an issue converting a date column in varchar format to date format in presto-sql. The date_column is in this format : '9/5/2022', '12/23/2022', '%null%' etc.

I have tried the following queries:

```sql
SELECT
DATE_PARSE(date_column, '%Y-%m-%d')
FROM table

SELECT
CAST(date_column AS DATE)
FROM table
```

And there is always this error popping up:

> Caused by: io.prestosql.jdbc.$internal.client.FailureInfo$FailureException: Invalid format: "11/30/2022" is malformed at "/30/2022"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided format (see the [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions)) represents year, month, day separated by `-` while your data is in month, day, year separated by `/`. Change the format accordingly:

```sql
SELECT DATE_PARSE('11/30/2022', '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Output:

```
          _col0
-------------------------
 2022-11-30 00:00:00.000
```

Note that strings like `'%null%'` (not just `null` strings) will be invalid also. If you really have those - you should consider wrapping the parse call into `try`.

Comment: That well works, thank you Guru Stron!